# ms_access-forms to reports

Tags: ms-access

I created a form in access. I created a combo-box to display all clients, once a particular client is clicked a sub_data-sheet appears showing the (many) details of that client(in table form)

Now I need to create a report listing that client name with that clients details as the form has it, the twist come when the report must be able to contain more than 1 client,

how do i go about doing that,

thanks a mil

Comment: What if you just 'group' the report by client?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a report and subreport; use the query that the combo is based on as the recordsource for main report and the query that the subform is based on as the recordsource for the subreport.

This does not seem to be a programming question.

Comment: Forms and reports are structured very alike in Access, so what works for one will work for the other.  The feature in the report object that isn't found in a form is grouping, which you can ignore as you transition to a report.

Comment: Second thought:  You can ignore report grouping, but depending on what you mean by "the twist comes when ...", grouping may get you just what you need.

Comment: Third thought:  ... which is what PowerUser said, I notice!

Comment: The combo box isn't going to allow for multiple clients. The source for the main part of the report should only have one record/client, so grouping isn't needed. The sub report data takes care of that.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to filter the report when you run it. I don't know if you have a command button on a form-maybe two. Your vba could look like this.

'Single Client using a filter on the combo box value (Assuming some sort of Client identification number)
DoCmd.OpenReport , acViewPreview, , "[ClientID]=" & cmbClientID, acWindowNormal

'All clients
DoCmd.OpenReport , acViewPreview, , , acWindowNormal

Comment: -1.  The integrated features of reporting seem to be a natural for this, per Remou.

Comment: How is a filter not an integrated feature of reporting?